# How to add blockchain.info API key to pibitcointools

Tags: api, python

I have a query-intensive app I'm building that keeps timing out with the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 72, in <module>
    array = bitcoin.multiaccess (bitcoin.unspent(address), 'value')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitcoin/bci.py", line 136, in unspent
    return f(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitcoin/bci.py", line 54, in bci_unspent
    raise Exception(e) 
Exception: Quota Exceeded (Req Count Limit)
```

I assume I'm making too many calls to the server. So I requested and received an API key from blockchain.info, but I have no idea how to add it to either the  pybitcointools library (maybe it should go in bci.py, maybe somewhere else?) or my test.py program, to get it to use my API key instead of connecting normally to blockchain.info.

Any help you can give would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: I'll send you the link to a fork of pybitcointools shortly which solves this issue